# SwiftUI View Controls

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to use `.alert` and `.onAppear` for one of my views, and I want `.onAppear` to be called first, because `.alert` is dependent on a variable in `.onAppear.` Any way to specifically order ui controls?

Comment: if alert is showing only by activating variable in onAppear then order of modifiers does not matter

Comment: Edit some terms

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI provides a declarative user interface rather than the more imperative paradigm used in UIKit. So instead of using a sequence of commands to modify state and views separately, a SwiftUI view is defined as a function of its state.

So in this case the order of `.onAppear` and `.alert` does not change the presentation of the alert.

```
struct Demo: View {

    @State var isAlertPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onAppear() {
                self.isAlertPresented = true
        }
        .alert(isPresented: self.$isAlertPresented) {
            Alert(title: Text("Alert!"))
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, when the Text view appears, `.isAlertPresented` changes to true. Separately, an Alert is added that will display whenever `.isAlertPresented` is true.

The example below has the same result, even changing the order of the two ViewModifiers.

```
struct Demo: View {

    @State var isAlertPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .alert(isPresented: self.$isAlertPresented) {
                Alert(title: Text("Alert!"))
        }
        .onAppear() {
            self.isAlertPresented = true
        }
    }
}
```